# Jest unexpected token error with Firebase (vite js + typescript + react)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, jestjs, redux-toolkit

I am trying to test my application.

### The test that I am trying to run, has as objective to test a thunk function (redux toolkit).

I am also using Firebase for authentication and Firestore for storage.
I have this error in console.

```js
    Jest encountered an unexpected token

 /home/fml/Escritorio/Projects/Journal-app/node_modules/firebase/app/dist/index.esm.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import { registerVersion } from '@firebase/app';
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

    > 1 | import { FirebaseOptions, initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
        | ^
      2 | import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
      3 | import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore/lite';
      4 | import { getEnvironments } from '../utils';

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1796:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/firebase/config.ts:1:1)
```

This is the test I am trying to run. I am trying to mock my providers file, which consists of Firebase authentication methods, but it doesn't seem to work.

```js
import { checkingCredentials } from '../../../src/redux/auth/authSlice';
import { checkingAuthentication } from '../../../src/redux/auth/thunk';

jest.mock('../../../src/firebase/providers');

describe('thunk.ts (auth)', () => {
    
    const dispatch = jest.fn();

    beforeEach( () => jest.clearAllMocks() );

    test('should invoke checkingCredentials', async() => {
        
        await checkingAuthentication()( dispatch );
        expect( dispatch ).toHaveBeenCalledWith( checkingCredentials() )
        
    });
    
});
```

This is my jest config (**jest.config.ts**):

```js
export default {
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(css|less|sass|scss)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
  },
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts'],
  transformIgnorePatterns: [],
}
```

This is my jest setup (**jest.setup.ts**):

```js
import 'setimmediate';
import 'whatwg-fetch';
import { config } from 'dotenv';

config({
    path: '.env'
});

jest.mock('./src/utils/getEnvironments', () => ({
    getEnvironments: () => ({ ...process.env })
}));
```

#### Main Stack:

- Vite JS: 2.9.9
- React JS: 18.0.0
- TypeScript: 4.6.3
- Firebase: 9.8.3
- reduxjs/toolkit: 1.8.2

These are my installed dependencies

```json
{
  "name": "journal-app",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test": "jest --verbose=true"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@cloudinary/react": "^1.4.1",
    "@cloudinary/url-gen": "^1.8.0",
    "@lottiefiles/react-lottie-player": "^3.4.7",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.2",
    "firebase": "^9.8.3",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.2",
    "@types/react": "18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.24",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "1.3.0",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.7",
    "cloudinary": "^1.30.0",
    "daisyui": "2.15.4",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^28.1.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^28.1.1",
    "postcss": "8.4.14",
    "setimmediate": "^1.0.5",
    "tailwindcss": "3.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "^28.0.5",
    "ts-node": "^10.8.1",
    "typescript": "4.6.3",
    "vite": "2.9.9",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.6.2"
  }
}
```

#### **How can I mock my file or how can I test the thunk function?**